# Unable to specify multiple attributes in handlebar

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am having problem specifying multiple attributes in any class at all.

if I have a key:value like

> {"class":"javascript handlebar-js"}

and use it like this
<<kbd>div class={{class}}</kbd>><<kbd>div</kbd>>

it only spits out 
<<kbd>div class="javascript"</kbd>><<kbd>div</kbd>>

when I want
<<kbd>div class="javascript handlebar-js"</kbd>><<kbd>div</kbd>>

Sometimes I have one class sometimes I have multiple classes
Is there any other way to do this besides putting all classes inside an array and using a with + each statement to move through each class and cramping up my object with unnecessary arrays? Not that I am sure if using said method would work.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried `<div class="{{class}}">`?

Comment: BTW, `...using a variable, helper, or partial named class causes errors in IE browsers. (Instead, use className)`.

Comment: -Pointy That did the trick, Thanks
-raina77ow thanks for the insightful tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by Pointy, enclosed class definition into simple or doubles quotes.

Based upon this data (`{"className":"javascript handlebar-js"}`),

`<div class="{{className}}"> </div>` will produce `<div class="javascript handlebar-js"></div>`

`<div class={{className}}> </div>` will produce `<div class="javascript" handlebar-js></div>`

The two results will not be interpreted in the same way in the browser.